# Cocoa Mac application using Microsoft Exchange Services 2007

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, exchangewebservices

Can anyone provide a suggestion on the best way to use Exchange Services 2007 in a Mac application using Cocoa?  I need to access Inbox mail messages and their headers to parse the information I need.

I have written an implementation in my .NET application, but of course .NET provides some nice libraries to handle all the complex types and such.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Cocoa doesn't really have any decent SOAP libraries available that I'm aware of.  You could either try to access Exchange via IMAP if it's enabled for your server (e.g. with [MailCore](https://bitbucket.org/mronge/mailcore/)) or embed another language with better SOAP support (e.g. Java, Python).  [Here's](http://code.google.com/p/imap2exchange/wiki/ExchangeWebServices) an example of using Java/JAXWS to talk to EWS.

Microsoft has an [EWS Java API](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi) but it was apparently so poor-quality that they pulled it.  However, there's a link to the download on that page if you want to try it anyway, and it's open source so you could potentially fix any bugs you ran into.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I will take a look at your example.

Comment: After looking around I am still unable to find an example of calling Exchange Web Services from objective-c.  Is this even possible?  IMAP won't be an option, and I would really like to do this in objective-c over java so it can be ported to the IPAD.  Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Doc,
I came across this EWS OSX Widget in my search for the same thing.  It would be good to know if this works for you.

http://ewsmacwidget.codeplex.com/releases/view/16559